# Displaying geometry returned from ST_Buffer in PostGIS with OpenLayers?

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, geoserver, polygon, buffer

I'm using PostGIS, GeoServer and OpenLayers, and the thing is that I want to display the geometry result from a query like this:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 100)'), 500);
```

To perform queries I'm using Java, the line I use to perform a query is the following:

```
resulset = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

where resulset is a `ResultSet` type object, when I convert it to String I get the following:

```
org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@163b102
```

My question is how do I interpret that to display the POLYGON I suppose is in there in a layer? or am I doing something wrong? Hope someone can help me with this question.

Answer (score 5):

You can perform operations with WKT you return from consultations in postgis

SELECT ST_ASTEXT(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 100)'), 500));

you recieve WKT and use Openlayer to convert the wkt to geometry and feature. for example   :  var elemento = New OpenLayers.Format.WKT().read('textWktFromRecordColumn');

I hope it helps. greetings

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the WPS addon for GeoServer - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/processes.html which provides a clean interface for this sort of query.

Answer (score 0):

if you use geodjango from server side, you can achieve this with performing raw SQL queries...

for example :

with models in model.py

```
Person.objects.raw('''SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 100)'), 500);''');
```

or importing some module for connection and directly querying:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 100)'), 500))
row = cursor.fetchone() # .fetcall()
```

this is data retrievalling work for executing raw sql...

and last word about this geoquery